# How to upload and run Laravel project on host?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, host

Hey I'm new Laravel user. Using Windows 7.

I made my project on computer, on wamp. I have migrations (create tables and etc).

I uploaded my project to my host and it's not working. That's becuase i need to use `php artisan serve` command in the composer. But I can't do it! Becuase it's an host.

How should I run the project when it's on host?

Please help! thakns!

Comment: Pretty much everything you need is located [within this blog entry](http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host)

Comment: do everything locally then upload the results.

Comment: Try using Laravel Homestead - its a virtual box and allows you to work on Windows 7 without issue.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange his local installation works fine, his question is about running Artisan commands on a web host which probably doesn't provide any shell access and only (S)FTP access.